# Where is the certificates folder for Docker Beta for Mac

Tags: docker

I can't find any certificate files created by `Docker Beta for Mac`. I need it for my IDE connection to Docker.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> I installed the Docker Beta for Mac and found no ~/.docker/ directory.

As mentioned in "[Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox¶](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)"

> With Docker for Mac, you get only one VM, and you don’t manage it.
>   It is managed by the Docker for Mac application, which includes autoupdate to update the client and server versions of Docker.
>
> If you need several VMs and want to manage the version of the Docker client or server you are using, you can continue to use `docker-machine`

So you will see certs in `~/.docker/machine` only if you decide to create your own.

With the new Docker for Mac setup, check if there are any certificates in `/Applications/Docker.app/` (as in `/Applications/Docker.app/Contents/Resources`)

If you rely on the default HyperKit, then there is no need for certificate in order to contact the VM with docker command.
As illustrated by the comments below (and the [OP Kroderia](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1867608/kroderia)'s [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38291654/6309)), **the default VM is only accessed through `/var/run/docker.sock`**.
As [Ellis](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2044848/ellis) comments below, that can be a challenge for some software like [PyCharm](https://www.jetbrains.com/pycharm/):

> when it (PyCharm) tries to connect it produces:

```
Cannot connect: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: 
Could not initialize class org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket"
```

[Issue 153973](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-153973) suggests:

> This is due to that Docker plugin is bundled in PyCharm. It could be updated manually but even with Docker 2.3.1 the problem with Docker Python interpreter will not be fixed.
>   The next **PyCharm 2016.2 EAP** with the fix is on its way.
>
> The workaround with `socat` you described will be available in the next PyCharm 2016.2 EAP. The next EAP will be released soon with the updated Docker plugin version.

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2375,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CONNECT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

Comment: They don't appear to be anywhere within Docker.app. I'm having the same issue as the OP - PyCharm integration, in my case.

Comment: @Ellis do you have stated to create a VM or connect to the Hyper-V VM (for the new one)? Did you do a `docker-machine ls`, or `docker-machine ssh default`?

Comment: No machines are listed under docker-machine ls, and docker-machine ssh default displays 'Host does not exist: "default"'. But clearly the Docker for Mac VM is running, as I have docker containers running using docker-compose.

Comment: @Ellis Then I suspect the default VM is accessed through `/var/run/docker.sock` only, no certificate needed (not until you decide to create a new machine)

Comment: Ah, yes, that would make sense. The socket exists, but it seems like PyCharm may only support TCP/IP. I can enter the 'API URL' as `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` but when it tries to connect it produces "Cannot connect: javax.ws.rs.ProcessingException: Could not initialize class org.newsclub.net.unix.NativeUnixSocket".

Comment: @Ellis OK, I have included your comment in the answer for more visibility.

Comment: Thanks. For now it seems like Docker for Mac has not been designed with access (e.g. from IDEs) in mind! e: or perhaps it's the IDEs that need updating.

Comment: @Ellis Maybe there is a bug in progress on the IntelliJ PyCharm side? (https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissues%2FPY)

Comment: @Ellis I have updated the answer with that bug report.

Comment: Ah, cheers, I was just searching around myself and came across some other bugs but that's the one I actually needed!

Comment: 2.3.2 Docker plugin, PyCharm build 162.1237.1. It now informs you to run the command socat... when you try to enter unix:///var/run/docker.sock as the API URL. After doing this (and pointing the URL at localhost) the server connects to the Docker Beta system and allows u to select an image. However, It gets stuck 'waiting for connection' while connecting to the debugger. It starts the container and inside if I run ps aux I see python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 10.0.2.2 --port 61276 --file /opt/project/app.py. The file is there too, Any pointers?

Comment: @LaserJesus Not sure; it is best to make a new question (with a reference to this one) in order to bring help on the specifics of your issue.

Answer (score 7):

@VonC takes the best answer.

I just wanna to provide my solution about this question. The question is about using a connection to manage docker. In fact I am using `Docker Integration` in IntelliJ.

1. As mentioned in [Docker for Mac vs. Docker Toolbox](https://docs.docker.com/docker-for-mac/docker-toolbox/)

> At installation time, Docker for Mac provisions an HyperKit VM based on Alpine Linux, running Docker Engine. It exposes the docker API on a socket in `/var/tmp/docker.sock`

However, it's not the truth, the real socket path is `/var/run/docker.sock`. You can now use `unix:///var/run/docker.sock` as API URL in `Docker Integration`, not certificate files are needed.

2. Guess what, `Docker Integration` ver 2.2.*, which works in the stable build(2016.1), failed with unix connection in Mac and got fixed in ver 2.3.1, which works in the preview build(2016.2). Which means if you want to make it works properly, you will need to update your IntelliJ to the preview build and install the newest plugin.
3. Here's the worst thing. The `Docker Integration` ver 2.3.1 got `NullPointerException` when deploying the Dockerfile, which works in the stable version of IntelliJ and `Docker Integration` ver 2.2.* via `http` connection. I have sent an email to the plugin author and waiting for a furthur solution.

Comment: Well spotted on the socket side. +1

Comment: 2.3.2 Docker plugin, PyCharm build 162.1237.1. It now informs you to run the command socat... when you try to enter unix:///var/run/docker.sock as the API URL. After doing this (and pointing the URL at localhost) the server connects to the Docker Beta system and allows u to select an image. However, It gets stuck 'waiting for connection' while connecting to the debugger. It starts the container and inside if I run ps aux I see python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 10.0.2.2 --port 61276 --file /opt/project/app.py.  The file is there too, Any pointers?

Comment: @LaserJesus any luck getting PyCharm to play nice with Docker for Mac?

Answer (score 0):

Spent the last few hours, but it's finally working:

1. downloaded [pycharm early access program](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=23004355)
2. setup [docker hub registry](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/2016.3/docker-registry.html) as described here
3. pycharm -> preferences -> project interpreter -> add remote -> Docker compose.