# How do I Debug a Flask app in PyCharm with the Docker for OSX Beta?

Tags: macos, debugging, docker, flask, pycharm

I was previously able to debug my Flask application in PyCharm 16.1 with the Docker Machine. I could build the Docker container and then specify it as a remote Python interpreter. I recently upgraded Docker to use the Beta for OSX where it's able to run natively and no longer requires the docker-machine VM. After reading through a related question here: [Where is the certificates folder for Docker Beta for Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38285282/where-is-the-certificates-folder-for-docker-beta-for-mac) I am still having issues when I try and debug.

I have the 2.3.2 Docker plugin for PyCharm and PyCharm build 162.1237.1. It now informs you to run the command

```
socat TCP-LISTEN:2376,reuseaddr,fork UNIX-CLIENT:/var/run/docker.sock
```

when you try to enter unix:///var/run/docker.sock as the Docker API URL. After doing this (and pointing the URL to tcp://localhost:2376) the server connects to the Docker Beta system and allows u to select an available container image as the remote interpreter. However, when you try and debug the application it gets stuck 'waiting for connection' while connecting to the debugger. In this scenario PyCharm does start the Docker container and if I exec into the container I can run `ps aux` and see:

```
python -u /opt/.pycharm_helpers/pydev/pydevd.py --multiproc --qt-support --client 10.0.2.2 --port 61276 --file /opt/project/app.py.
```

The file /opt/project/app.py is in the container and I can successfully start the flask app by running `python /opt/project/app.py`. How do I get PyCharm to successfully run this file and connect the debugger so I can step though the code in the IDE, for example.

Comment: Pycharm hasn't rolled out support for the newly-reinvented Docker beta.

Comment: @PaulEveritt : Any known hack to deal with this in the mean time?

Comment: I suspect using the most recent release of Docker, instead of the beta.

Comment: @PaulEveritt AFAIK the most recent release of Docker which runs natively on OSX is still in beta. I don't have these issues with Docker Toolbox (which I've rolled back to for the moment). https://blog.docker.com/2016/06/docker-mac-windows-public-beta/